# P-channel MOSFET blows/opencircuit after being on for a very short time

Tags: mosfet

About 5 minutes after powering up my circuit the LED turns on and the MOSFET appears to have failed (no longer turning off when gate voltage is applied). The MOSFET is a [IRLML5203](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML5203-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566868da261d). I have replaced it 5 times now and it seems that it keeps blowing.

[image]

I brought down the voltage from 12 V to 5 V and it still appears to do the same (after the same time).

I do notice that the LED is very dimly lit up when the same voltage is applied to the gate, so there is a small current leakage (however, I believe this is expected). The MOSFET doesn't seem to short or go opencircuit (when contunuity testing).

I wonder if maybe these are just badly made MOSFETs (they have been bought from AliExpress), or am I just missing something completely?

Comment: It should be off - completely. Being Ali Express, is it possible they sent you N-channel MOSFETs instead?

Comment: I am suspecting it is an issue with the mosfet. Even though its aliexpress the seller is DSSRQI (8yrs 99.3%). As if I disconnect the gate voltage it lights up LED then reapply voltage and it turns off apart from the very slight glow. Switching it on/off appears reliable until it suddenly just stays on permently. If the curcuit seems sound then I guess the mosfet is the problem.

Comment: If you are leaving the gate disconnected it could be a static electricity thing. What if you keep a 100k or 1M resistor permanently between the gate and ground so it doesn't get disconnected when you unplug the other resistor? I also remember this phenomenon where a MOSFET designed for switching purposes, with a too low gate voltage, could cause all the heat dissipation to be concentrated on one part of the chip. This occurs in the region of operation where higher temperatures cause higher current, which according to the datasheet, is when -Vgs is below about 3.7 volts.

Comment: (I guessed that you are turning it on by just unplugging R1 from your breadboard)

Comment: I did suspect something like this hence why I just left it conencted to see (which was about 5min or so and it went into this state) - I tried adding a 1M resistor from gate to ground just to see but next one took about 3 min and it just lit up.

Comment: What is your source of 12V? I suspect it may not be as "clean" as you think -- any chance of high-voltage spikes?

Comment: 12v Supply is from a desk power supply. I tried also on a battery as well (just a regular style car battery - it was at around 13v) - I don't believe there would be anything crazy high spikes.